# Getting undefined in component after service success

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing login with Angular 5, so in my service I have

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    debugger;
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:58607/api/account/Login', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }), { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
      });
  }
```

and into typescript component I have something like:

```
signin() {
    this.loading = true;

    this._authService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this._router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      },
      error => {
        this.showAlert('alertSignin');
        this._alertService.error(error._body);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

problem is when I debbug, when debugger reach component, `data` comes undefined as next picture:

[image]

Someone have an idea what occurs there, service execute correctly with status 200, but I don´t know why I receive undefined on component? Regards

Comment: I think you forgot to return in your map function

Comment: I´m very new in Angular, what do you mean with map function? where can I found it? @mr.void

Comment: In your service you map over the observable you get from http.post. Map will only fill new entries to the result if you return something in the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you have to return in the map function:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    debugger;
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:58607/api/account/Login', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }), { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          /** RETURN **/
          return user;
        }
      });
  }
```